# Dynamic URL in nginx configuration

Tags: nginx

I am quite new to managing http server. How should I configure nginx to achieve behaviour like this: When there is a request for example.com/foo, nginx should serve index.html from /var/www/foo directory. When there is a request for example.com/bar, nginx should serve index.html from /var/www/bar directory.

The second part of URL (foo, bar) should not be hardcoded in nginx.conf, I need something like variable.

This is part of my nginx.conf, I tried something with variable in location section but I can't get this working.

```
server {
        listen       188.xxx.xxx.xxx;

        #access_log  logs/localhost.access.log  main;

        location ~/(\d+) {
            root   /var/www/$1;
            index  index.html index.htm;
        }
}
```

Comment: You don't need to do _anything_ special for this! Set `root /var/www;` and you're done.

Comment: This indeed works, however only if I call `http://188.xxx.xxx.xxx/foo` or `http://188.xxx.xxx.xxx/bar`. How to get this working with my domain: `http://example.com/foo`, `http://example.com/bar` ? I tried putting `server_name example.com;`, but didn't help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to set the root folder to make things work as expected.

Setting this within `server {...}` directive is enough, no need to specify a sub `location` directive.

Like this :

```
server {
   listen 188.xxx.xxx.xxx:80;
   server_name example.com;
   root /var/www;
   index  index.html index.htm;
}
```

Then, just ensure you have `index.html` or `index.htm` in

- /var/www/foo
- /var/www/bar
- /var/www/whateveryouwant

Comment: Working great but only when URL is like this `http://188.xxx.xxx.xxx/foo`. when I change the address to `http://example.com/foo` I get `403 Forbidden`. Do you have any idea why this is happening?

Comment: @user1091733 Should not happens. Please can you update your question with your vhost config ? There is certainly a bad config somewhere.

Comment: @user1091733 My idea is that DNS does not resolve example.com with ip 188.xxx.xxx.xxx. Check DNS resolution.

Comment: Thank you for response. Weird thing - if i put `index.html` into `/var/www` and go to `http://example.com` - I get the proper result. The problem appears only if I try to access `index.html` located in  `/var/www/foo` by entering `http://example.com/foo` - then I get `403 Forbidden`. My vhost config looks excatly like the one you posted in your answer.

Comment: @user1091733 It could be a permission issue. Check for the `x` bit for others on `/var/www/foo` folder : `chmod o+x /var/www/foo`

Comment: Somehow I can access `http://example.com/foo` now and I get the index.html. But there's another problem - I changed the content in index.html and when I enter `http://example.com/foo`, I get the old version (304 Not modified response). If I go to `http://188.xxx.xxx.xxx/foo` I get the new version. I guess this is cache related but I didn't turn on any cache in nginx.